# How can i add same value to every item in list, turning it into alist?

Tags: list, mapping

I tried to use this code, but it returns (k k k k k)

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) 'cons x '(k))
        '(a b c d e))
```

What am i doing wrong here? Why doesn't cons work?

Comment: n.b. `(lambda (x) 'cons x '(k))` is a function which returns `'(k)` (after a couple of pointless evaluations).  That mapcar therefore *should* be returning `((k) (k) (k) (k) (k))` which is different to what you've said.

Comment: Also, be careful with things like `'(k)` in that context -- that's the *exact same list* being placed in each cell of that output.  If you were to `setcar` any one of those `(k)` instances to, say, `j`, then not only would the entire list become `((j) (j) (j) (j) (j))`, but the *lambda function itself* would now be returning that same`'(j)` as well (unless it was re-`read`).  You frequently want `(list 'k)` rather than `'(k)`.

Answer (score 6):

Just syntax error. To create your alist, use to following:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (cons x 'k))
        '(a b c d e))
```